# Scroll() function when refreshing pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I would like to use the scroll() function to detect when I scrolldown the page.
for example, this code :

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    alert();
});
```

My problem is that this code works when I'm at the top of the page and scrolldown, but when I'm not at the top of the page and I refresh the page, I have the alert BEFORE any scroll.

I would like it to work only when I scroll. NOT when I'm already at the middle of the page without scrolling yet.

Do you have any advice? I hope I'm clear.

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is, after a reload you are scrolling to the last position of your site.

You could set a timeout befor assigning the scroll event to window like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
 $(window).scroll(function () {
  alert();
 });  
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a [plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/) that detects up/down mouse wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery try to resolve by doing if condition in scrollTop() method. This will give u the scroller position.

Always better if u use  JavaScript or jquery on document ready.